# Acessing Windows performance Monitor from java code

Tags: java, windows, perfmon

I have a java program which need to create, update and read counters in the Windows performance Monitor.

I have searched stackoverflow for previous posts about this issue and found two main articles proposed:

First is [this one](http://www.developer.com/java/ent/article.php/3087741/Hooking-to-PerfMon-from-Java.htm). It relies on unbearable Win32 API and doesn't give a complete step by step tutorial. Also, I do not know this Win32 API and do not wish to study it now.

The second is [this one](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073044/java-se/access-windows-performance-monitor-counters-from-java--part-1.html). It seemed to me like a better option, but it relies on nsclient component which I couldn't find anywhere on the web. However, there is nsclient++, but I am not sure it supports java (I posted there a question about it) and anyways, the tutorial is not based on it.

Maybe some has a better solution?

Many thanks, Tal.

Comment: I thought there was command line tools to extract this information.  If so you can run this from Java.

Comment: Do you mean something like logman?